# INDIRECT() returns #VALUE! unexpectedly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

Background: I'm using Excel functions to parse a lot of data out, essentially creating a flexible pivot table. It sorts a lot of race timing data by car, etc. In this portion of the sheet, I'm searching for the minimum segment times for each car. The rest of the sheet avoids macros and VBA so I'd like to avoid that here.

Issue: My formula worked when there are no zeros, but sometimes there are zeros that I need to exclude. My array formula is pretty complicated, but the change I made that broke it is this:

OLD (working):

```
{=min(if(car_number = indirect("number_vector"), indirect("data_vector")))}
```

NEW (non-working):

```
{=min(if(and(car_number = indirect("number_vector"),not(0=indirect("data_vector"))), indirect("data_vector")))}
```

I am using `INDIRECT()` with this exact argument several times in the formula. However, in this particular instance (inside the `NOT()`), it returns #VALUE! instead of {data1;...;datan}. **Please see the screencaps below.**

Before evaluation:

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-L8akIeJU_MU/Ud3Lsl1c5mI/AAAAAAAAAEY/MfrwGRi_29k/w565-h338-no/before.PNG]

After evaluation:

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SQK3fc33fzo/Ud3LsqjeOQI/AAAAAAAAAEU/oAmcxtr6tFU/w563-h303-no/after.PNG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your AND function might be a problem - AND only returns a single result not an array of results as required, try using multiple IFs like this

`=min(if(car_number = indirect("number_vector"),IF(indirect(data_vector)<>0, indirect(data_vector))))`

Note that I also used <> rather than using NOT

Are data vector and number vector the same size and shape? (both vertical?)
why are there quotes around one but not the other?

Comment: I'll try this approach, your logic makes sense.

Both vectors are the same size and shape, they are different columns in the same table. The quote thing was a mistake in my pseudocode (fixed).

Comment: OK - if that doesn't work then the problem may be COLUMN function that I see from your screenshot - COLUMN sometimes causes problems because it returns an array like {4} when you expect 4 - this can then cause evaluation problems - to fix wrap COLUMN in another function like SUM, e.g. **SUM(COLUMN())**